# How to group only VISIBLE posts?

Tags: posts, wp-query

Good afternoon

With the help of a fellow user here I am finally able to display all posts on a single page with the respective post month as a divider between the groups.

So it looks something like this:

```
February 2021
----------------- 
post 5 
post 4


January 2021
------------------ 
Post 3 
Post 2 
Post 1


...and so on...
```

So far so good.
But I have an additional "filter" on that page, which shows or hides posts on click. e.g. you're able to filter by post author and if a post does dot match the filter the post is being hidden with the addition of a "style=display:none" on its container.

Big question: How do I display the divider only if there are visible posts for that divider group?

```
<?php
    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query( [
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    ] );

    $dividers = [];
?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div id="list_allposts">
        <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php $post_date = get_the_date( 'F Y' ); ?>
            <?php if ( !in_array( $post_date, $dividers ) ): ?>
                <?php $dividers[] = $post_date; ?>
                <div class="divider">
                    <?= $post_date; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>

            <!-- Post code here -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

PS: At the moment I am just hiding the divider as soon as there is an active filter. But maybe there is a better solution so that we can have dividers ALTHOUGH there is an active filter. Would make the page just MORE PERFECT..

Comment: Sounds like your filter uses custom JS, so this isn't really a WP question.

Comment: if you're hiding the posts using javascript and a `style` attribute then there is no way to do this from WP, it has to be done in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the divider an attribute, ie: `data-target=".group_20211006"` and add class to the post container, ie: `class="blah group_20211006"`. After the filter changes, loop through each divider and check if there's any visible post container with matching date value.

### HTML

```html
<!-- First Group -->
<div class="divider" data-target=".group_20211001">October 1, 2021</div>
<div class="post-1 group_20211001">...</div>
<div class="post-2 group_20211001">...</div>
<div class="post-3 group_20211001">...</div>

<!-- Second Group -->
<div class="divider" data-group=".group_20211006">October 6, 2021</div>
<div class="post-1 group_20211006">...</div>
<div class="post-2 group_20211006">...</div>
<div class="post-3 group_20211006">...</div>
```

### jQuery

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).on('change', '.myfilter', function(){
      $('div.divider').each(function(e, el){
        if ( $($(el).attr('data-group')).is(':visible').length > 0 ) {
          $(el).show();
        } else {
          $(el).hide();
        }
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

I haven't tested, but this should be the concept to make it work.